# Card Matching Game on Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am current building a simple card matching game in python, with a 5x4 (row*column) grid, in which two players try to match a deck of twenty cards (2,10 of only suit Hearts) * 2.

The problem I am running into is in iterating through the deck, printing the cards out in a grid fashion so it would look like this:

```
-----     -----    -----     -----
-   -     -   -    -   -     -   -
 4-H       6-H      7-H       8-H
-   -     -   -    -   -     -   - 
-----     -----    -----     -----
```

The code I currently have is below:

```
#needed import for shuffle function
from random import shuffle

#class for my deck
class Deck:
    #constructor starts off with no cards
    def __init__( self ):
        self._deck = []

    #populate the deck with every combination of suits and values    
    def Populate( self ):
        #Heart, Diamond, Spades, Clubs
        for suit in 'HDSC':
            #Jack = 11, Queen = 12, King = 13, Ace = 14
            for value in range(2, 15):
                if value == 11:
                    value = 'J'
                elif value == 12:
                    value = 'Q'
                elif value == 13:
                    value = 'K'
                elif value == 14:
                    value = 'A'
                #add to deck list
                self._deck.append(str(value) + '-' + suit)

    #populate the deck with only hears hearts and all cards except face cards and aces (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) twice
    def gamePop( self ):
        suit = 'H'
        for x in range(2):
            for value in range(2, 11):
                self._deck.append(str(value) + '-' + suit)

    #shuffle the deck with the random import             
    def Shuffle( self ):
        shuffle( self._deck )

    #length of the deck
    def len( self ):
        return len( self._deck )

    def stringIt( self ): 
        #Returns the string representation of a deck
        result = ''
        for c in self._deck:
            result = result + str(c) + '\n'
        return result

#class for a single card
class Card:
    #constructor for what type of card it is
    def __init__( self, value, suit ):
        self._value = value
        self._suit = suit
        self._card = self._value + self._suit

    #print the type of card    
    def Description( self ):
        return ( self._card )

    #overloaded ==
    def __eq__( self, another ):
        if ( self._card == another.Description() ):
            return True
        else:
            return False
#main function which plays the game
def main():

    #sets player counters to zero,
    pOneCount = 0
    pTwoCount = 0

    #creates the deck to be put on the board
    gameDeck = Deck()
    gameDeck.gamePop()
    gameDeck.Shuffle()

    print(gameDeck._deck)
    currentCard = 0
    for row in range(5):
        for card in range(0,4+i):
            mystring = 
        print ('-------  ' * 4)
        print ('|     |  ' * 4)
        for x in range(4):
            print ('|  ' +gameDeck._deck[currentCard]+'|'),
            currentCard += 1
        print ('|     |  ' * 4)
        print ('-------  ' * 4)
```

Edit: I cleared up the code which I've tried.

The current output is this:

```
-------  -------  -------  -------  
|     |  |     |  |     |  |     |  
|  7-H|
|  5-H|
|  7-H|
|  9-H|
|     |  |     |  |     |  |     |  
-------  -------  -------  -------
```

Comment: What he has tried is the code he posted. What he's missing is a good explanation of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it to include the code I've tried.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your current output is?

Comment: The code as presented won't produce any output at all.  The `main` function has a dangling `mystring =`, which is a blatant syntax error.  Also, there is a reference to `i` which isn't defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in the def main():

def main():

```
    print ('-------  ' * 4)
    print ('|     |  ' * 4)
    for x in range(4):
        print ('|  ' +gameDeck._deck[currentCard]+'|'),
        currentCard += 1
    print ('|     |  ' * 4)
    print ('-------  ' * 4)
```

the * 4 just mean that this:

```
print ('-------  ' * 4)
```

will become this:

```
print ('-------  ' + '-------  ' + '-------  ' + '-------  ' )
```

it can also be type as:

```
print ('-------  -------  -------  -------  ' )
```

so. your problem is here:

```
    for x in range(4):
        print ('|  ' +gameDeck._deck[currentCard]+'|'),
        currentCard += 1
```

this would print as:

```
|  7-H|
|  5-H|
|  7-H|
|  9-H|
```

you need to put it as something like this:

```
        print ('|  ' +gameDeck._deck[currentCard]+'|'+'|  ' +gameDeck._deck[currentCard+1]+'|'+'|  ' +gameDeck._deck[currentCard+2]+'|'+'|  ' +gameDeck._deck[currentCard+3]+'|')
```

so it would print in one line like how you want it:

```
    |  7-H|  |  5-H|  |  7-H|  |  9-H|
```

here is the code that i clean up a little. if it work like it should, it should work:

```
def main():

    #sets player counters to zero,
    pOneCount = 0
    pTwoCount = 0

    #creates the deck to be put on the board
    gameDeck = Deck()
    gameDeck.gamePop()
    gameDeck.Shuffle()

    print(gameDeck._deck)
    currentCard = 0
    for row in range(5):
        for card in range(0,4+i): 
        print (' ------- ' * 4)
        print (' |     | ' * 4)
        print (' | ' +gameDeck._deck[currentCard]+' | '+' | ' +gameDeck._deck[currentCard+1]+' | '+' | ' +gameDeck._deck[currentCard+2]+' | '+' | ' +gameDeck._deck[currentCard+3]+' | ')
        print (' |     | ' * 4)
        print (' ------- ' * 4)
```

oh, and like John Y say (copy and paste):

The main function has a dangling mystring =, which is a blatant syntax error

here what i use to test, because the whole code don't work for me, i just tested the print part:

```
print (' ------- ' * 4)
print (' |     | ' * 4)
print (' | ' +"1-H"+' | '+' | ' +"2-H"+' | '+' | ' +"3-H"+' | '+' | ' +"4-H"+' |  ')
print (' |     | ' * 4)
print (' ------- ' * 4)
```

that got me:

```
 -------  -------  -------  ------- 
 |     |  |     |  |     |  |     | 
 | 1-H |  | 2-H |  | 3-H |  | 4-H |  
 |     |  |     |  |     |  |     | 
 -------  -------  -------  ------- 
>>>
```

Comment: Looks like OP may have been trying to use the Python 2 trailing comma on the `print` to suppress the newline, but is actually using Python 3, which doesn't work that way. (And even if he were suppressing the newline, he'd then have to issue another `print` to actually print the newline.)

Comment: well, my print works. just tested the print part because the whole codez don't work for me, see answer